# parse json news feed array android

Tags: java, android

I have an json feed from bbc in this format

```
{
  "name": "ticker",
  "entries": [
    {
      "headline": "text",
      "prompt": "LATEST",
      "isBreaking": "false",
      "mediaType": "Standard",
      "url": ""
    },
    {
      "headline": "text",
      "prompt": "LATEST",
      "isBreaking": "false",
      "mediaType": "Standard",
      "url": ""
    }, 
   etc...........
```

My code is as follows:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http:/......");
try{
    JSONArray  item = json.getJSONArray("entries");
    for (int i = 0; i<item.length(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject e = item.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONObject title = e.JSONObject("headline");
        map.put("title", "Title:" + e.getString("headline");
    }
}
```

It gives me the error `"java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"`

I also tried leaving out `JSONObject title = e.JSONObject("headline");` and it gives me a path error (note

Comment: That seems like a pretty self-explanatory exception.

Answer (score 0):

You want e.getString("headline"), not e.JSONObject

Comment: I tried that before but it gives me a Source not found error (Choreographer.doCallbacks(int,long) line:558..

Answer (score 0):

use

```
JSONObject e = item.getJSONObject(i);
map.put("title", "Title:" + e.getString("headline");
```

instead of

```
    JSONObject e = item.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject title = e.JSONObject("headline");
    map.put("title", "Title:" + e.getString("headline");
```

becuase `e` json object not contain any other json object it only contains keys and corresponding values

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it gives me Source not found error (Choreographer.doCallbacks(int,long) line:558.. –

Comment: What you are doing in Choreographer.doCallbacks method?

Comment: I am not doing anything with Choreograoher, that is just what pops up as a tab on the degbugger (with a source not found message) when i run the code as shown above.